# Run SpecFlow test infinity times

Tags: specflow

I have a SpecFlow test that fails if you run it enough times. How can I take the existing SpecFlow test and make it run infinity times until it fails? (Ideally I'd like to count how many times it takes.)

My initial guess was to just call the binding methods that the test script ultimately calls - but I keep getting null pointer exceptions. Apparently SpecFlow is initialising something that I'm not.

My next guess was to try to launch the auto-generated code for the test feature, but it seems to want all sorts of data from the SpecFlow framework that I don't know how to generate.

All I want to do is run the test multiple times. Surely there *must* be some way to accomplish this utterly trivial task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was trying too hard. Here's what I came up with:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public sealed class StressTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var thing = new FoobarFeature();
        thing.FeatureSetup();
        thing.TestInitialize();

        var n = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("------------ Attempt {0} ----------------", n);
            thing.Scenario1();
            thing.Scenario2();
            thing.Scenario3();
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

I've got a `Foobar.feature` file, which autogenerates a `Foobar.feature.cs` file containing the `FoobarFeature` class. The names of the scenario methods obviously change depending what's in your feature file.

I'm not 100% sure this works for tests having complex setup / teardown, but it works for my specific case...